# How to search inside pdf using php/html?

Tags: php, html, search, pdf

hy everyone, i want to make a search engine that can search into "many" pdf files. i want to search the content inside pdf files, not only the title. this application is for archiving my files, so i can search matching words easily. for example in google, you can use "filetype:.pdf home" and the result will show all pdf files that contain word home on it content. so can you help me with this web-based application?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running on linux and you can run system commands, you can try using 'pdftotext' command to convert pdf files to plain text, and then index that.

Just remember, that the text will be in display order and not semanticly correct order (two column articles will give very strange results), so displaying the text will make no sense and searching for sentences might not work correctly.